Closing the contour in Mellin transform
Good morning, I am computing some Mellin transforms and I encountered the following integral
$$ \int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} \frac{ds}{2\pi i} \frac{z^{-s}}{s-d} \frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(a-s)\Gamma(b-s)}{\Gamma(c-s)} $$
where $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers and $z>0$. I know I can compute this integral by closing the contour in the complex plane but I don't understand whether I should close it on the left or on the right. In particular, I don't know how to estimate the large $s$ behaviour of the gamma function. Can someone tell me and explain how to prove it? I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but my complex analysis is not great.

Mathematica indicates the inverse Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}s^{-1}\left\frac{\Gamma(s), \Gamma(a-s), \Gamma(b-s)}{(s-d), \Gamma(c-s)}\right=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits{\xi-i \infty}^{\xi+i \infty} \frac{(\Gamma(s), \Gamma(a-s), \Gamma(b-s))}{(s-d), \Gamma(c-s)}, z^{-s} , ds\=\frac{\pi z^{-d} \csc(\pi d), \Gamma(a-d), \Gamma(b-d)}{\Gamma(1-d), \Gamma(c-d)}-\Gamma(a), \Gamma(b), \Gamma(d), , _3\tilde{F}_2(a,b,d;c,d+1;-z),,\quad a,b,c,d>0$$ is only valid for $d<\Re(s)<\min(a,b)$ which suggests your integral bounds are incorrect.
